# How to Handle One-to-Many Relationship Mapping in JPA/Hibernate with Embedded Entities

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity AccountContact with fields id, accountId, and a list of Contact entities representing account contacts. The Contact entity is embedded within AccountContact.  I don't want to use two different tables for that. How can I properly map this one-to-many relationship in my entity? Any suggestions for handling such mappings.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account_contact
(
    id         INT PRIMARY KEY,
    account_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    phone      TEXT NOT NULL,
    name       TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_contact")
class AccountContact(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    val id: Int,
    @Column(name = "account_id", nullable = false)
    val accountId: String,
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(
        name = "account_contact",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)]
    )
    val contacts: Set<Contact>
)

@Embeddable
data class Contact(
    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = false)
    val phone: String,
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    val name: String
)
```

Error: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK2cv8b63x720avx5k79vw8kggq:account_contact [id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (account_contact [id,name,phone])

Comment: It's logically incorrect for table to refers to itself with MtO association using one column as FK and PK. Either it is unique or not. But the main question: why do you need AccountContact entity? As I suppose, you have Account entity, so it can have a OneToMany association with Contact, doesn't it?

Comment: I have only one table. The account_id is obtained from an external service. I need to be able to retrieve a list of user contacts based on their account_id. The query should join the table with itself to return the list of contacts. This can be done using jdbcTemplate, but I'd like to try it using JPA

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative method to accomplish this task, which I prefer

[image]

[image]